# Renaming Hundreds of Files Prior to Import, Needs Drastic Speed Up

Tags: vb.net, system.io.file

We have an import that renames files in a directory prior to actually importing any of the data. It runs fine on my machine but some of our users have hardware limitations and when the file count gets in the 500+ range it starts to slow down or even stops all together (users have not supplied errors, of course).

I have already sped up this process quite a bit, but I feel the issue has to be in using "File.Move()" to rename the files, there has to be a better solution, right?

**Code (customer name removed for anonymity):**

```
For Each file In items
    Dim fName As String = IO.Path.GetFileName(file)
    If (Not fName.ToUpper.Contains("xxxxxxxx")) Then
        rname.renameFile(ftpPath & "\", fName, CustomerName & "_" & fName)
    End If
Next
```

**renameFile:**

```
Public Sub renameFile(ByVal filePath As String, _
                      ByVal origfileName As String, _
                      ByVal newfileName As String)
    Try
        File.Move(filePath & origfileName, filePath & newfileName)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New ArgumentException(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

All I've done to the code was clean up the first chunk, it was using "IO.Path.GetFileName" everytime instead of just naming it to a variable, I saved myself about a half a second off of 9 seconds on 707 files, not too bad for a small change.

For reference, I ran the code again after the files already contained the desired string and it went through all of them in 1ms.

**EDIT - (Another attempt using "My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile"):**

```
For Each file In items
    Dim fName As String = IO.Path.GetFileName(file)
        If (Not fName.ToUpper.Contains("xxxxxxxx")) Then
            My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile(ftpPath & "\" & fName, CustomerName & "_" & fName)
        End If
    Next
```

**THIS WAS ACTUALLY SLOWER, from 8,497ms to 12,957ms... gah.**

Comment: Do you actually need to rename the file or can you just create a folder with the name you like and move the file into it. Not sure if this would be a performance improvement or not.

Comment: It appears that you have already identified the problem as a hardware limitation. Perhaps you could rewrite the renaming to be a [backgroundworker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx) and give some sort of progress indicator to the user. As long as the user sees progress is being made, they will hopefully not interfere with it.

Comment: @TerryCarmen this was in place long before me, and we are assuming somewhere there are queries using this included string in queries, we'd like to keep it as is to not risk disturbing things.

Comment: @AndrewMorton the users understand it is slow, but what is the real reason for hoping to make this more efficient is that it seems to just not work when there are too many files, without the error codes I am assuming it must be memory related.

Comment: @haag1 There is no point in assuming, that is the same as guessing. Is there actually an error raised, or do the users simply give up and press the reset button on the computer? You must find out what the real problem is to be able to solve it ;)

Comment: @AndrewMorton I know, I am only assuming because as i stated in the original post, the users have not yet supplied any error codes (and this particular user is out on vacation for a week). Regardless of an error or not I was still looking to see if there were any better optimized ways to rename these files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you could try.. If the various machines have multi-core processors, you could try parallelizing the loop like this. It might not make a vast difference, but if the hard disks support Native Command Queuing, then there may be some benefit.

```
Parallel.ForEach(items, Sub(file As String)
                            Dim fName As String = IO.Path.GetFileName(file)
                            If (Not fName.ToUpper.Contains("xxxxxxxx")) Then
                                renameFile(ftpPath & "\", fName, CustomerName & "_" & fName)
                            End If
                        End Sub)
```